# MVC é viável e recomendado em projetos Android?

Tags: android, mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Estou trabalhando em um projeto mobile onde é necessário migrar uma aplicação legada, que foi desenvolvida para **Windows Mobile 6.1** (*handheld*), para o **Android**.

Esta aplicação foi desenvolvida utilizando **C#**, com arquitetura em 3 camadas, dividido em grupos de classes de *View*, Negócios e Dados (*winForms, BLL e DAL*).

Ao migrar para o **Android**, é viável, ou recomendado a utilizar esse tipo de arquitetura também, ou pode haver problemas? Ou existe algum padrão de arquitetura melhor recomandado para aplicativos grandes, em android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!
Tudo depende de seu projeto.
Você pode adotar no Android a arquitetura que quiser para desenvolver seu app, sendo que não existe uma recomendada oficialmente para aplicativos Android, pois estas são apenas conceitos que podem ser aplicadas em qualquer linguagem.
No caso de um aplicativo grande, uma boa opção é aplicar um conceito que separe bem a regra de negócios, a interface e o modelo de dados (MVC) para assim ficar fácil a manutenção futura. Se a arquitetura que você mencionou faz isto, não vejo problemas ou maiores dificuldades em aplicar ela em um aplicativo Android.

Comment: Legal, a arquitetura que mencionei já faz isso sim. Minha dúvida era em questão ao Android mesmo, se tinha alguma melhor recomendada, como estou iniciando no Android, não tinha conhecimento a respeito.

Comment: utilizar o modelo MVC facilita muito a manutenção do código